# Namespaces when using XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been searching on this form to an answer of my question but haven't found any results. The problem is that I should be using a namespace to convert the XML below using XSLT. When adding the namespace to the XSLT, the convertion doesn't work.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TED_EXPORT xmlns="http://publications.europa.eu/TED_schema/Export" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://publications.europa.eu/TED_schema/Export/R2.0.8.S02.E01 TED_EXPORT.xsd" 
DOC_ID="146944-2014" 
EDITION="2014085">
<TECHNICAL_SECTION>
  <RECEPTION_ID>14-147821-001</RECEPTION_ID>
  <DELETION_DATE>20150422</DELETION_DATE>
  <FORM_LG_LIST>DA DE EN ES FI FR EL IT NL PT SV CS ET HU LT LV MT PL SK SL GA BG RO HR </FORM_LG_LIST>
  <COMMENTS>From Convertor</COMMENTS>
</TECHNICAL_SECTION>
</TED_EXPORT>
```

XLST file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      
    xmlns:ted="http://publications.europa.eu/TED_schema/Export#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">


<xsl:template match="/">
    <rdf:RDF>
        <xsl:value-of select="//@EDITION"/>
    </rdf:RDF>
    test
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/ted:TECHNICAL_SECTION">
  Technical Section
 </xsl:template>
```

Note that I simplified this XSLT tool in order to focus on the namespace problem.

When removing the namespace from both the XML and the XSLT, the conversion works. Does any of you have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: you posted xslt twice but XML is missing.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I've added the correct code now.

Comment: There is a difference between the namespaces in your xml and xslt, the # at the end

Comment: "*the convertion doesn't work*" That's not a good description. Post the result you expect to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, your stylesheet "doesn't work" because:

1. The `</stylesheet>` closing tag is missing;
2. All the declared namespaces contain a redundant `#` suffix;
3. This template:

   `<xsl:template match="/ted:TECHNICAL_SECTION">`
   `...`

   does not match anything because `TECHNICAL_SECTION` is not the root element. Try instead:

   `<xsl:template match="ted:TECHNICAL_SECTION">`
   `...`

Comment: Thanks, these coments worked great on my mistakes! I got it all working now.